# How to open/mount a BKF file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, file-format, bkf

1. Will the [Microsoft Windows NT Backup - Restore Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7DA725E2-8B69-4C65-AFA3-2A53107D54A7&displaylang=en) overwrite my files if I use it to open this file?
2. How to use it under Windows 7? (Windows 7 doesn't have the Removable Storage Management feature necessary to use it)
3. Can it be extracted by a decompressing tool?
4. Can it be mounted like a ISO file?
5. Can it be transformed into a virtual HD file?
6. How?

Comment: 1. Yes, most likely it will, that is the wrong utility for W7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run NT Backup under Windows 7.  Here are some [directions](http://www.slickit.ca/2009/07/running-nt-backup-under-windows-7.html) on how to do it.

Comment: We normally like answers that include the directions on how to do something and not simply link to some other website that might or might not exists a year later.

Answer (score 3):

you have critical data contained in a NTBackup file (.BKF) and want to restore it in Windows 7.

1. Open the Control Panel. (Classic View)
2. Click on the Backup and Restore Center icon.
3. Click on the Restore Files button.
   **NOTE:** To restore a backup not shown here, click Advanced restore instead and click Advanced restore (Restore files from a backup made on another computer).
4. Dot what you want to restore, latest or older backup files, and click on Next.
5. Select the Backup files to restore and click on Next. 
   NOTE: This will be from the backup file that you selected in step 4. If it is not here, then click Search to navigate to the backup files location.
   A) To Remove the Selected Backup Click on the Remove button.
   B) To Remove All the Backups Listed Here
   **NOTE:** Click on the Remove all button.
6. Select where you want to restore the files to and click on Start Restore. 
   **NOTE:** Normally you would pick Original Location to replace the files with the backup files. Otherwise, you can save the backup files to another location to manually replace the files you want with the backups.
7. You will now see the progress window.
8. If you already have a copy or older copy of the file in that location from step 6, then you will see this window below. If not, then you will see step 9 below.

   "**Just click on Copy and Replace to replace the file with the backup copy of the file**"
9. When the restore is completed, Click on Finish.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do but see this, use "View and request hotfix downloads" at the top of the link page to request the W7 program.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=974674

Or see this

http://windows7themes.net/how-to-open-bkf-file-in-windows-7.html

.

Answer (score 0):

I'm resurrecting this old topic hoping to save an headache for those who need to recover the content of BKF files using Windows 10: if that's your case, you can use the **NT5Backup** tool by **STSanford**, which is available here:

- [Original website](http://www.stsanford.com/pebuilder/)
- [Mirror website](http://www.ryadel.com/download/nt5backup-by-stsanford/) (with only the required files)

Just unpack the archive to a single folder of your hard-drive and you're good to go. It will warn about a missing service (you can safely ignore the warning) and then let you restore any BKF file.

For additional info regarding this topic, you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/open-bkf-files-in-windows-10-without-ntbackup-with-nt5backup/).